# Elasticsearch Java Client create query for field with list of values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, java-client

```
String searchText = "TEST";

.query(q -> q.bool(b -> b .must(c-> c .match(t -> t .field("FIELD NAME").query(searchText) ))
```

I need to pass String Array to query. Whats the best way I can do it.

Comment: can you explain what you want to achieve ?

Comment: ```
GET /index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
              "JCODE": ["TRF","HPM"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```
I need to achieve something like this using Java client 8.6

Comment: You can refer this for the answer. Thank you @Amit for trying to help out.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-java-client-create-query-for-field-with-list-of-values/328040/3